# CNN object localisation

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have data-set of images (24 x 24). I want to predict `center_x` and `center_y` for each object in each image. I have a file wwich contains `center_x` and `center_y` of each object in the image.

The number of objects in each image is less than or equal to 2.

I tried to solve this problem with the Convolution Neural Network with 'Linear' Activation function in the last layer, but it did not achieve good results.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(80, 3 ,activation='relu',input_shape=(24,24,3)))
model.add(Conv2D(64,3  , activation='relu' ))
model.add(MaxPool2D(2,2))
model.add(Conv2D(64,3  , activation='relu' ))
model.add(MaxPool2D(2,2)) 
model.add(Conv2D(128,1  , activation='relu' ))
model.add(Flatten())   
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4, activation = 'linear'))
```

Output:

```
[center_x_of_first_object , center_y_of_first_object ,center_x_of_second_object , center_y_of_second_object ]
```

1. if there is no object in the image the output will be: [0,0,0,0]
2. if there is one object in the image the output will be:       [value_x,value_y ,0,0]
3. if there are two objects in the image the
       output will be: [value_x,value_y ,value_x2,value_y2]

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: you are looking for an object detection solution, i think models like **YOLO** might help [this might be useful](https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/real-time-object-detection-with-yolo-yolov2-28b1b93e2088)

Comment: YOLO and FASTER-CNN  it can not help me because my images is very small 24x24 but those algorithms based on pretrained models like Vgg , and those models   not accepted the images less then 32x32 .

Comment: resize your images into *32x32* and believe me you will got what you want perfectly, i did the same with `googlenet` before and resized my images before feeding the model from **56x56** into **256x256** and the results where perfect.

Comment: thanks , i will try .